# Jackson map different attributes based on json in the same class

Tags: java, jackson

I have a `class Response` which has an attribute `data`.

A json file is mapped to this object. The `data` attribute can be of type `TaskData` or `SubmitData` on the json.

If the json has the object of type `TaskData` the object mapper must map to `TaskData` class or should map to `SubmitData' class.

Comment: Do you mean that you need the deserialiser to automatically detect which form of JSON it is looking at and pick the appropriate TaskData or SubmitData, or do you know in advance which type it will be for a particular unmarshalling call? Can you edit the question to show examples of the two different JSON formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to type your `Response` class as follows: `public class Response<T>`.

Then, when deserializing the input, provide a `TypeReference` to jackson to indicate the desired type.

See this example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestJacksonTyping {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Response<TaskData> taskResponse = new Response<TaskData>();
        TaskData taskData = new TaskData();
        taskData.setTaskTitle("Some title");
        taskResponse.setData(taskData);
        Response<SubmitData> submitResponse = new Response<SubmitData>();
        SubmitData submitData = new SubmitData();
        submitData.setSubmitValue(256);
        submitResponse.setData(submitData);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        mapper.writeValue(sw, taskResponse);
        String taskResponseJson = sw.toString();
        mapper.writeValue(sw = new StringWriter(), submitResponse);
        String submitResponseJson = sw.toString();
        Response<TaskData> deserializedTaskResponse = mapper.reader(new TypeReference<Response<TaskData>>() {
        }).readValue(new StringReader(taskResponseJson));
        Response<SubmitData> deserializedSubmitResponse = mapper.reader(new TypeReference<Response<SubmitData>>() {
        }).readValue(new StringReader(submitResponseJson));
        System.out.println(deserializedTaskResponse.getData().getTaskTitle());
        System.out.println(deserializedSubmitResponse.getData().getSubmitValue());

    }

    public static class Response<T> {
        private T data;

        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

    }

    public static class TaskData {
        private String taskTitle;

        public String getTaskTitle() {
            return taskTitle;
        }

        public void setTaskTitle(String taskTitle) {
            this.taskTitle = taskTitle;
        }
    }

    public static class SubmitData {
        private int submitValue;

        public int getSubmitValue() {
            return submitValue;
        }

        public void setSubmitValue(int submitValue) {
            this.submitValue = submitValue;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume Polet, helped me write something generic..!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by Guillaume Polet, and if you can modify the JSON schema, this can also be done a little bit smoother using Jackson's [Polymorphic (de)serialization](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) via annotations:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.Class, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
class Data {}

class TaskData extends Data {}
class SubmitData extends Data {}
```

This will write out the full Java class name as an additional `@class` property. The json needs to include the `@class` property on input, however.

Instead of `JsonTypeInfo.Id.Class` it is also possible to perform explicit naming

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.Class, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@dataType")
@JsonSubTypes({
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value=TaskData.class, name="task"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value=SubmitData.class, name="submit")
})
class Data {}

@JsonTypeName("task")
class TaskData extends Data {}
@JsonTypeName("submit")
class SubmitData extends Data {}
```

This will yield an additional synthetic field `@dataType`, which will need to be present in the input.

**If you cannot make the type explicit in the input JSON, you will need to stick to the manual approach.**

Comment: Thanks for your response. This would do if i could change the input.json. Unfortunately i don't that freedom. Will anyway try achieving this sometime